# SQL - LIMIT query

Tags: mysql, sql

`SELECT *
FROM Employees
ORDER BY EmployeeID
LIMIT(5,3);`

I want to select only 3 records that are the 5th, 6th and 7th records in a table called Employees. This Employees table consists of 100 records.

I tried using "LIMIT" function as stated in the code but it was not working - I do not understand where have I gone wrong.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Remove parenthesis from limit clause
SELECT * FROM Employees ORDER BY EmployeeID LIMIT4,3

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's got to be MySQL, q.v. the comments under my answer below.

Comment: I was simply trying it out in w3schools

Comment: @RakeshSoni thanks for the input, now it's working. That was so silly of me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for MySQL's `LIMIT` is:

```
LIMIT offset, count
```

where `offset` means the number of records from the top which you want to *skip* completely, and `count` is the total number of records to be returned.

So if you want 3 records starting from the 5th position, then use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
ORDER BY EmployeeID
LIMIT 4, 3;
```

### Demo

Comment: `Limit` is not limited only `MySQL` it could be `postgresql` or `sqlite`, etc.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I believe Postgres requires `OFFSET` to appear explicitly, so the OP can't be Postgres.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Here is a [demo](http://rextester.com/KOT60818) showing that MySQL's shortened `LIMIT` syntax is not supported on Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT 5, 3;
```

and also query below can be help you

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```